# How can I check whether file exists or doesn't in specific folder in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, uri

I use this code:

```
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule public/.* - [L]
```

and it doesn't work.

for example, I want that URL:
http://example.com/style.css
to be Interpeted like this

public/style.css

if style.css exists in public directory. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule public/.* - [L]
```

**EDIT**

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contains the full path to the requested file. So e.g. `/var/www/example.com/index.html`. So adding `public/` to the front will result in `public/var/www/example.com/index.html`, which never exists. You therefore use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` which contains `/var/www/example.com`, and `%{REQUEST_URI}` which contains `/index.html`

Also note that `-f` and `-d` need a full path, not just a wwwroot-relative one.

Comment: No problem. See edit above. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: How can I do that all the files that doesn't exist will return 404?

Comment: I don't get it. All none-existing files should just result in a 404, regardless of the above rewrite-rule.